# Matplotlib | How to plot a line that's straight (rectangular)

Tags: matplotlib, plot

does anyone know if there is a way to plot a line in matplotlib that is straight?

To demonstrate what I mean look at this picture:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFPnR.png)

If I use matplotlib.plot() the data will be connected in the way the red line connects the dots since it's the shortest distance (euclidean). But I want to plot it like the black line, extending the line forward until a the line passes a new value at which point it turns 90 degrees up or down to reach the new datapoint. This sort of thing is called manhattan distance, but I can't seem to find anything about how to plot it.

If anyone has any suggestions in matplotlib or in some other package such as Bokeh please let me know.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html

Comment: `plt.step(x, y, where='post')`

Comment: For bokeh: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/step.html